# Ember .get doesn't return correct value

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

So i have this ember object "lineup", when i use

```
lineup.get('stations').length = 396
```

but it is wrong, if i inspect that object, and use _data

```
lineup._data.stations.length = 429
```

it is the correct one,

Lineup stations is got from ember-data request payload manipulation like this

```
if (payload.stations) {
     payload.stations = payload.stations.map(function(s) {
         s.logo = s.logoFilename ? 'http://cdn.tvpassport.com/image/station/100x100/'+s.logoFilename : null;
         delete s.logoFilename;
         return Ember.Object.create(s);
      });
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Could you post code that creates payload? Also you can try ```lineup.get('stations.length');```

Comment: is it that lineup._data.length is different to lineup.get('stations')?

Comment: The payload is fetched from server side

Comment: sorry, i put the wrong code, it should be lineup._data.stations.length

Answer (score 1):

`Ember.get` will sometimes return an `ObjectProxy` or and `ArrayProxy`. Sometimes in ember-data you could also get an `PromiseObject` or and `PromiseArray`.

If you are in a computed property you can access the data directly, but never use normal JS-dotnotation after a .get! Always do `obj.get('full.path.to.prop')` and never `obj.get('full').get('path').get('to').get('prop')` or `obj.get('full').path.to.prop`.

If you are not in a computed property (for example, you are in an action) use `.then` on a `PromiseObject` or `PromiseArray`.

---

So for a computed property:

```
len: Ember.computed('lineup', {
  get() {
    return this.get('lineup.stations.length');
  }
})
```

---

And for an action:

```
alertLen() {
  this.get('lineup.stations').then(stations => alert(stations.get('length'));
}
```